# Get users IP and insert it into database without lag

Tags: php, mysql

I'm logging IP's on my index page, the page most people will be visiting. I want to log IP's for statistics. All info is going into a MySQL database. My problem is lag.

It takes around a second to generate the page for me. I want it to be as quick as possible, and the server connecting to the database and inserting the logs. Now (I believe) the users gets on the index page, and before the whole page is loaded my script is executed, which connects to the DB and inserts the data. So the user has to wait a second for the data to be inserted. I want the user to visit the page and then the data be inserted into the DB.

This is my code.

Index.php

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(substr($ip,0,4) != "192."){ //Don't log my local IP
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
    include("ext/functions.php"); 
    logger($page,$ip);
}
```

Functions.php

```
<?php 
function logger($page, $ip){ 
    $logr = mysqli_query(mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$statDB),
    "INSERT INTO logs (page, DATE, ip) VALUES ('$page', NOW(), '$ip')"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Connecting to your database should take MUCH less time than a second.

Comment: You can use a PHP array to log the IP's instead of a MySQL database. Then you can use the cronjob to insert it in the database and reset the array without wait a second.

Comment: why not use the Apache access log, on by default in almost all set ups.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to do it after page loaded completely:

Create a php page and store your php/mysql code into it like "storeip.php"

then simply download and insert jquery library into your index page like:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var ip = "<? echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>";
var page = "<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>";

$.post("storeip.php","ip="+ip+"&page="+page);
});
</script>
```

so you can manage the posted "ip" and "page" variables in your "storeip.php" file

Comment: That didn't work as I had thought. Thought it removed the lag (and didn't log).

I google'd for quite a while and found that replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" removed some delay. 

I did some checking, an empty page just connecting to the server using "localhost" took 1.020792 seconds

With "127.0.0.1" it took 0.001272 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can flush your output buffers so that the user can see the actual page, and execute the insert afterwards. Whether you'll actually be able to do this depends on your actual implementation, but in case it's simple, you could put your code at the very end of your script, and right before it's executed:

```
ob_flush();
flush();
session_write_close();  //optional; it will allow your users to navigate away before the slow operation is complete (if you are using sessions)
//your logging code goes here
```

- You may need to call `ob_start();` at the beginning of your script.
- this will only make your page display faster, it will not make it load faster (the loading icon will still show)

In a different note, as others have mentioned, one second for a simple operation as this is too much. You must try and see why it gets so long. First, check whether it is the connection or the query itself to blame. In the latter case, if the logs table is too big, you must consider:

- Removing any (or all) indexes on the table. Indexes are good for reads but can slow down writes, so if you're using this table mainly for writes, you should reconsider its structure.
- Reconsider the [table engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html) you are using. Different table types have different performance characteristics; Check the [archive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html) for example.